# easydropdown jquery plugin fails to work with two selection elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do not include the easydropdown.js library,my code works but the css functionality is not fully implemented(only easydropdown.css file is included)

```
  <script>
       $(function() {

            $("#text-one").change(function() {
          $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
         });
        });
  </script>


  <div id="page-wrap">
<select id="text-one" class="dropdown">
    <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
    <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
    <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
   </select>

   <br />

   <select id="text-two" class="dropdown">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Any suggestion how this could work in full mode?

Comment: Dies anyone know what should we do in order to get the desired result??